# How do you calculate the displacement of a projectile with an initial height?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, displacement

I am trying to make a simulator like [this](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Physics-Interactives/Vectors-and-Projectiles/Projectile-Simulator/Projectile-Simulator-Interactive) and I'm already done with the calculation of the displacement x using this formula:

[image]

But the problem is that my projectile always start at 0.0m in height, and I would like to be able to set the initial height of the projectile, so what would me the formula needed? also how do you calculate the displacement y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial conditions are given as $x_0=0, v_{x0}=\dot{x}(0)=v_0\cos\theta$ and $y_0=h, v_{y0}=\dot{y}(0)=v_0\sin\theta$. Since the only force acting is gravitation, Newton's equations are given as $$\ddot{x}=0$$ $$\ddot{y}=-g$$ Their solution with the given initial conditions are $$x(t)=v_0t\cos\theta$$ and $$y(t)=h+v_0t\sin\theta-gt^2/2$$ From there you can get everything: the equation of the trajectory, time of flight, maximum height, displacement, length of the trajectory etc.